# How to ignore double quotes in Spark Dataframe where we read the input data from CSV?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a Spark dataframe (without double quotes) by reading input from csv file as mentioned below.

[image]

Here is my code, but no use so far.

```
val empDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("quote", "\"")
  .option("escape", "\"")
  .load("EmpWithQuotes.csv")
  .toDF()
```

My expected output is not to add double quotes to out but I am getting an output with junk.

```
+---+-----+----------+----+
|eno|ename|      eloc|esal|
+---+-----+----------+----+
| 11|�abx�| �chennai�|1000|
| 22|�abr�|     �hyd�|3000|
```

Comment: is it possible to post exact data instead of image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with Spark over Scala and it removed the quotes from the columns:

```
df = df.withColumn("ename", regexp_replace(col("ename"), "“", ""))
    .withColumn("eloc", regexp_replace(col("eloc"), "“", ""))
    .withColumn("ename", regexp_replace(col("ename"), "”", ""))
    .withColumn("eloc", regexp_replace(col("eloc"), "”", ""))
```

There must be something similar in the Python API of Spark too....

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Spark's default csv format and not `com.databricks.spark.csv` it should work as expected

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object EscapeQuotes {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    val pattern = "“|”"
    spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .csv("src/main/resources/sample.csv")
      .withColumn("eloc",regexp_replace(col("eloc"),pattern,""))
      .withColumn("ename",regexp_replace(col("ename"),pattern,""))
      .show()
  }

}
```

Comment: I have tried solutions given so far, but nothing is worked for me. Is there any alternate way please ?

Comment: Hi QuickSilver, I am getting an 'invalid escape character' issue for the statement ".option("escape", "\“")".

Comment: sorry posted wrong ans will come with the right one

Comment: Typography double quotes (“) and (”) are causing trouble to you and not ("). Please look closely and confirm. So that I can work on the solution

Comment: Yes, you're right. It contains (“) and (”) . Now I have included (") and tried , in this case I am not getting the junk as mentioned the question, but I am getting the same quotes into output also. Is there any solution to remove (") in output dataframe?

Comment: Have you added both quotes (“) and (”) as both are different quotes ?

Comment: Yes, when I use (“) and (”) -> I am getting junk in output. when use (") -> I am getting these same input quotes in output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are not normal double quotes. You could try to find which character is and escape it, or, you can take the substring (if you are confident every row has leading and trailing quotes):

```
empDF.withColumn("ename", substring(col("ename"), 1, length(col("ename"))-2))
```